# Non-flat partitions of a set

Tags: performance-tuning, probability-or-statistics, combinatorics, sets

A non-flat partition of a set is one where, when the elements of the set are on a grid, the partition does not contain subsets with elements from the same row. When the set is more irregular the same idea holds.

See e.g. Chapter 4 of G. Peccati and M. Taqqu. [Wiener Chaos: Moments, Cumulants and Diagrams: A survey with Computer Implementation.](https://www.springer.com/gb/book/9788847016781) Bocconi & Springer Series. Springer, 2011.

For example, when the set is a $3 \times 4$ grid of dots, we have an example flat and non-flat partition of the dots as follows.

Flat: [image]

Non-Flat: [image]

I have the following code, which arranges points on a grid, finds all the partitions, and selects all the non-flat ones:

```
range[x_, r_] := Module[{interval},
   i = IntegerPart[(x - 1)/r]; interval = Range[r i + 1, r i + r]];
qflat[x_, r_] := 
  AnyTrue[Subsets[range[#, r] & /@ x, {2}], 
   IntersectingQ[#[[1]], #[[2]]] &];
flatQ[par_, r_] := AnyTrue[par, qflat[#, r] &];
pickflat[par_, r_] := 
  Select[Transpose[{par, flatQ[#, r] & /@ par}], #[[2]] == 
      False &][[All, 1]];
Needs["Combinatorica`"];
par = SetPartitions[Range[1, 12]];
SetPartitions[Range[1, 12]] // AbsoluteTiming // First
pickflat[par, 4] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 14.811
>
> 351.011

The last step `pickflat` is quite long. Is there a trick which avoids the use of subsets here, which might optimise the code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not use [`Quotient`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quotient) to figure out what row each element belongs to, and then make sure there are no duplicates? For example:

```
fQ[part_, n_] := AllTrue[Quotient[part, n, 1], DuplicateFreeQ]
```

Comparison:

```
rand = RandomSample[par, 10000];

r1 = pickflat[rand, 4]; //AbsoluteTiming
r2 = Select[rand, fQ[#, 4]&]; //AbsoluteTiming

r1 === r2
```

> {0.71157, Null}
>
> {0.078211, Null}
>
> True

**Addendum**

By the way, you can represent your set partitions with a simple vector. For example, the following set partition:

```
{{1},{2,3,8},{4,7,9,10},{5,6,11,12}}
```

could be represented with:

```
{1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4}
```

which gives the set each index is associated to, that is:

$$\begin{array}{c}
 1\to 1 \\
 2\to 2 \\
 3\to 2 \\
 4\to 3 \\
 5\to 4 \\
 6\to 4 \\
 7\to 3 \\
 8\to 2 \\
 9\to 3 \\
 10\to 3 \\
 11\to 4 \\
 12\to 4 \\
\end{array}$$

Then, your list of set partitions could be represented as a matrix of integers. It is possible to define a compiled predicate that decides whether this new representation is flat or not. This compiled code would be orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: Ok thank you this is great. The compiled predicate idea will definitely help with the larger sets.